# How to fix org-dotemacs broken by latest update?

Tags: org-mode, debugging

I'm sorry to have to ask this, but lisp debugging is not one of my strengths. For some time I've been happily using Joe Bloggs's somewhat hoary but useful [org-dotemacs.el](https://github.com/vapniks/org-dotemacs) system to maintain my emacs init settings across several computers. The computers are using Fedora 28.

A standard Fedora update on June 10 broke that. I suspect the offending elements were:

```
Upgraded emacs-1:25.3-5.fc28.x86_64                         @fedora
Upgrade        1:26.1-1.fc28.x86_64                         @updates
Upgraded emacs-common-1:25.3-5.fc28.x86_64                  @fedora
Upgrade               1:26.1-1.fc28.x86_64                  @updates
Upgraded emacs-filesystem-1:25.3-5.fc28.noarch              @fedora
Upgrade                   1:26.1-1.fc28.noarch              @updates
```

The emacs init-debug returns this:

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  looking-at(nil)
    org-heading-components()
    org-in-commented-heading-p()
    org-babel-tangle-collect-blocks(emacs-lisp)
    org-dotemacs-load-blocks(nil skip)
    org-dotemacs-load-file(nil "~/.dotemacs.org" nil)
    org-dotemacs-load-default()
    eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/michael/.emacs" nil t)  ; 
    Reading at buffer position 525
    load-with-code-conversion("/home/michael/.emacs" 
     "/home/michael/.emacs" t t)
     load("~/.emacs" t t)
     #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x261c1d>)()
     command-line()
     normal-top-level()
```

Just naively, it looks like the problem is with the use of `looking-at` in the definition of `org-heading-components` in the file `org.el`. (This is `org-mode` version 9.1.13.)

So, back to the question: has anyone else had this problem, and does anyone have a suggestion as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/vapniks/org-dotemacs/pull/13/commits/836b1c4bea4e62a4d5646d0ba790e4fa5e88101e

This fixed it for me. Org-mode must explicitely be set in org-dotemacs.el.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. It would have taken me months or years to get to that. I hope it can be committed to the master branch, if I'm using the right verb.

Comment: Since this answer seems to have fixed your problem, you should accept it.

Comment: BTW, I was right in the diagnosis that org-mode is not set :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the argument of the `looking-at` is the variable `org-complex-heading-regexp` which starts out `nil` and is then set locally in a buffer when the buffer's major mode becomes `org-mode`. It seems that in your case, the latter does not happen and the variable remains nil. I presume that there is a buffer for the default `~/.dotemacs.org` after the failed initialization. If you switch to that buffer, does the status line indicate that the major mode is `Org`? If not, then that's the explanation. If yes, ah well, I tried...

If the mode *is* the problem, you might add

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))
```

to your `~/.emacs` *before* `org-dotemacs-load-default` is called.

Comment: Sadly, Nick, that doesn't work. Though it was a clever thought. The dotemacs.org buffer is using org mode by the time I see it, and adding the auto-mode item anyway (programming-by-sympathetic-magic on my part) doesn't work either. Sigh. BUT why looking-at is getting a nil argument is a good question.

Comment: Yes, it was a shot in the dark. The only other explanation that I can think of is that the evaluation is taking place in some buffer *other* than the `.dotemacs.org` buffer with a different major mode. But I really cannot see how that would happen. If you know how to use [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug), that's where I would turn to next.

Comment: Well, so here's the fing. Looking at the buffer list, it seems `.dotemacs.org` gets loaded /twice/. I do not understand that. The first copy is loaded in an org mode buffer, but `.dotemacs.org<2>` is in a fundamental mode buffer, which gets back to your orig. theory. Twice? Is that just a side-effect of the error handling system that reloads the file where the error occurred? Or something more sinister?